# how to call first index of tabbar view controller from app delegate?

Tags: swift, xcode

```
         let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ServicesVC") as! ServicesVC
        let editorViewController = newViewController
        let navEditorViewController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editorViewController)
        navEditorViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(navEditorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

ServiceVc is the first index viewcontroller of UITabbarViewController. I tried to call ServiceVc from AppDelegate, but it's not working. And I had onboarding screens after splash screen it is initial view controller of app.Please tell me solution.